# How to increment and update column in one eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Is it possible to update a timestamp (besides `updated_at`) and increment a column in one query? I obviously can

```php
->increment('count')
```

and separately

```php
->update(['last_count_increased_at' => Carbon::now()])
```

but is there an easy way to do both together.

```php
Product::where('product_id', $product->id)
    ->update(['count'=> $count + 1, 'last_count_increased_at' => Carbon::now()];
```

Without having to query and get the count first?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can specify additional columns to update during the increment or decrement operation:

```
Product::where('id',$id)
->increment('count', 1, ['increased_at' => Carbon::now()]);
```

It is more eloquent solution.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of this!

Comment: This feels like the more _eloquent_ solution.

Answer (score 69):

You can use the `DB::raw` method:

```
Product::where('product_id', $product->id)
    ->update([
      'count'=> DB::raw('count+1'), 
      'last_count_increased_at' => Carbon::now()
    ]);
```

Comment: Works great, can't believe I didn't think of that, was about to do the whole thing raw.

Comment: What if we don't have a matching record? How to create if no record found, without having to query and get the count first?

Comment: @AjjayArora While that really ought to be a new question, I'm not sure that can be done in a one-liner using just Eloquent. I think you actually would have to check if the product_id exists first.

Comment: @aynber Thanks pal for replying.

Answer (score 7):

With Laravel 8 you can now achieve this in a single query to create or update on duplicate key.

```php
$values = [
    'name' => 'Something',
    'count' => 1,
];
$uniqueBy = ['name'];
$update = ['count' => DB::raw('count+1')];

Model::upsert($values, $uniqueBy, $update);
```

If the model exists `count` will be incremented, if it is inserted `count` will equal `1`. This is done on the DB level, so only one query involved.

Read more about upserts: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#upserts

Comment: Upsert had another purpose you can use update for this and you'll be fine.

Comment: Update works for one model, the above works for multiple model values and/or a single one and increment count for each. I see this can be useful and accomplishes everything in 1 query as well.

Comment: No update can also work for multiple rows of the table you're referring to the update method on the model not the update method of the query builder.

Comment: Yes, but not with different values? So I still think this can be valuable depending on use case. I for example posted this after I had exactly this case, update many with different values and set visit count to +1

Comment: Sure of course I'm not implying that the upsert method is useless, but in the code that you provided above it could be changed with update and nothing will go wrong. All I'm saying is that it is unnecessary in this specific context and might mislead the future viewers.

Comment: Since the original question wasn't inserting a new record, upsert changes the behavior for this situation.

However, upsert has a very large benefit over updateOrCreate in the event you do want a new record created. firstOrCreate/updateOrCreate perform two queries (one to check and one to create) and that introduces a race condition on high traffic sites. As mentioned, upsert does everything in one query which eliminates that specific risk.